# Using BindingGroups for Displaying Validation Errors

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have the following WPF user interface: A listview that is bound to a collection.  There is a datatemplate that shows the particular data for each item in that collection.  The data template uses a stack panel to show the fields as well as owning the binding group.  For each of the items, a user will enter information and it will be validated.  If it fails, the error information is shown within the stack panel.  In addition to showing the errors here, I want to be able to mark the host ListView with some sort of information that there is a problem.  That way, I can affect the rest of the user interface basd on whether there is an error or not.  If I move the Binding Group up to the ListView, I will acheive that.  However, I will lose the stackpanel being able to show the errors.

In summary, I want to be able to propogate the error details (or at least a flag indicating an error) from the data template up to the host object (a list view in my case).  I am trying to do this with binding only so that I don't have to write any code behind.  But I am stumped as to how to do this.

Here is a quick snipit of code:

```
<ListView Name="LiquidDetailsList" Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding BatchToExecute}" ItemsSource="{Binding LiquidDefinitionList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,0" Name="LiquidRecord">
                <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
                    <BindingGroup Name="LiquidValidation" NotifyOnValidationError="True" />
                </StackPanel.BindingGroup>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBox Name="BatchLiquidLocation" Width="65" Height="25" Margin="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource standardTextBoxErrorStyle}" Background="PowderBlue"  SourceUpdated="LiquidComponent_SourceUpdated" TextChanged="LiquidComponent_TextChanged">
                        <Binding BindingGroupName="LiquidValidation" Path="Location" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" />
                    </TextBox>

                    <TextBox Name="BatchLiquidVolume" Margin="10,5,0,5" Width="65" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource standardTextBoxErrorStyle}" Background="PowderBlue" Tag="VOLUME"  SourceUpdated="LiquidComponent_SourceUpdated" TextChanged="LiquidComponent_TextChanged">
                        <Binding BindingGroupName="LiquidValidation" Path="Volume" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" />
                    </TextBox>

                    <CheckBox Name="BatchLiquidReuseTip" Margin="10,5,0,5" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="PowderBlue" Tag="REUSETIP" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                            <Binding BindingGroupName="LiquidValidation" Path="ReuseTip" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" />
                        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    </CheckBox>

                    <Button Name="DeleteLiquidButton" Margin="10,5,5,5" Width="25" Height="25" Click="DeleteLiquidButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center">X</Button>
                </StackPanel>

                <ItemsControl Margin="10,0,0,0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors), ElementName=LiquidRecord}"  IsTabStop="False">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding Path=ErrorContent}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: In running some additional tests, I think what I am looking for is something like the following.  At the parent ListView object, I would specify an ItemBindingGroup.  At the StackPanel that is the main container for a given item in the ListView, also specify a BindingGroup.  In this case, the validation done at the low level bound text box would be then available to both the StackPanel and the ListView.  However, this does not work as only one BindingGroup is used when they are both specified.  In this case, the lower level StackPanel gets precedence.